# После передачи одного класса в другой метод класса выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c++

После того как я создаю 3 предмета и добавляю их в план, я пытаюсь напечатать название и тип предмета, которые хранятся в плане, но на данном этапе `new_group.get_plan().print_plan();`код останавливается на некоторое время, после чего возвращает **0** и программа останавливается. Через debug я понял, что проблема связанна с памятью(сброс в стек). Но вот, что конкретно вызывает данную ошибку я так и не понял. Из-за чего это может происходить, что именно я делаю не так? Помогите пожалуйста, в смятении.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Mark {
private:
    int mark;
public:
    virtual void print_mark(){
        std::cout << mark;
    }
    virtual ~Mark() = default;
};

class Int_mark : public Mark {
private:
    int mark;
public:
    Int_mark() {
        std::string str_mark;
        std::cout << "Введите оценку: ";
        std::cin >> str_mark;

        int new_mark;
        try {
            new_mark = stoi(str_mark);
        } catch(...) {
            std::cout <<"Изменение неудалось. Вы ввели не число. Установлено значение по умолчанию.";
            mark = 1;
            return ;
        }

        try {
            if((new_mark < 1) || (new_mark > 5))
                throw 1;
            else
                mark = new_mark;
        } catch(int a) {
            std::cout << "Вы вышли за пределы допустмых значений. Значение оценки было установлино по умолчанию." << std::endl;
            mark = 1;
        }
    }
    ~Int_mark() = default;

    void print_mark() const {
        std::cout << "Ваша оценка: " << mark << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bool_mark : public Mark {
private:
    int mark;
public:
    Bool_mark() {
        std::string str_mark;
        std::cout << "Выберите оценку: " << std::endl << "1. Зачёт" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. Не зачёт" << std::endl << "Ввод: ";
        std::cin >> str_mark;

        int int_mark = stoi(str_mark);

        if(int_mark == 1) {
            mark = 1;
        } else if(int_mark == 2) {
            mark = 0;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Вы выбрали неверное значение." << std::endl;
            return ;
        }
    }
    ~Bool_mark() = default;

    void print_mark() const {
        if(mark == 0) {
            std::cout << "Ваша оценка: " << "Незачёт" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Ваша оценка: " << "Зачёт" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

class Subject {
private:
    std::string name_subject;
    std::string type_subject;
    unsigned hour_subject = 0;
    Mark *mark;
public:
    Subject() {
        std::string name_sub;
        std::cout << "Введите название предмета: ";
        std::cin >> name_sub;
        name_subject = name_sub;

        std::cout << "Выберите тип оценки: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. Зачёт" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. Дифференцированный зачёт/Экзамен" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Ввод: ";
        int select = 0;
        std::cin >> select;

        if(select == 1) {
            type_subject = "Зачёт";
            mark = new Bool_mark();
        } else {
            type_subject = "Дифференцированный зачёт/Экзамен";
            mark = new Int_mark();
        }
    }
    ~Subject() {
        delete mark;
    }

    std::string get_name_subject() {
        return name_subject;
    }
    std::string get_type_subject() {
        return type_subject;
    }
};

class Plan {
private:
    std::vector<Subject> list_subjects;
public:
    void add_subject(Subject subj) {
        list_subjects.push_back(subj);
    }
    void print_plan() {
        std::cout << "Предметы в плане:" << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < list_subjects.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << i + 1  << " " << list_subjects[i].get_name_subject() << list_subjects[i].get_type_subject() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

class Group {
private:
    std::string group_name;
    Plan group_plan;
public:
    Group() {
        std::string new_group_name;
        std::cout << "Введите название группы: ";
        std::cin >> new_group_name;
        group_name = new_group_name;
    }
    Plan &get_plan() {
        return group_plan;
    }
};

int main() {
    Group new_group;
    Subject new_subject1;
    Subject new_subject2;
    Subject new_subject3;
    new_group.get_plan().add_subject(new_subject1);
    new_group.get_plan().add_subject(new_subject2);
    new_group.get_plan().add_subject(new_subject3);
    new_group.get_plan().print_plan();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Где инициализируется поле group_plan?

Comment: В классе Group в private идё инициализация Plan group_plan.

Comment: Мой ответ на ваш вопрос "что я делаю не так?" _ абсолютно все делаете не так.  Как только начинаете писать, дайте себе отчет что и для чего  делаете. Нельзя так просто взять и  написать что угодно, а потом ждать результата. Имейте привычку генерировать исключения только там, где это логически оправдано и т.д.

Comment: *Помогите пожалуйста, в смятении* - я в смятении с вами, держитесь... Например, в смятении - зачем у вас в одном классе по два поля `mark`?

Comment: Я так понял, что вы про класс Subject. Там у меня в одном поле объявляется оценка типа Int, а во втором типа Bool

Comment: Подвисает/вылетает ваша программа (зависит от среды запуска) из-за того, что действительно у вас несколько раз убивается память по одному и тому же адресу *mark, а создается лишь один. Но в целом, надо бы поработать над архитектурой, потому что это винегрет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в классе Subject. Нужен как минимум копирующий конструктор. Потому что под *mark  память выделяется 1 раз, а удаляется несколько.